# How can I convert this date and time format to datetime?

Tags: python, csv, datetime, dataframe

I need to convert a certain date and time format to datetime, by reading a .csv file. Values are in column "Date_start" and "Date_end". The file has ~8760 lines, but the initial date format is "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm" but somewhere along the data it changes to  "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm".

I have tried nearly everything. pd.to_datetime keeps asking for mapping. new columns based on d.time and d.date erase the latter format dates because of the '-'.

```
df17_raw.head()
Out[4]: 
      Date_start       Date_end    ...      Total_Ah   Power_kW
0  1/1/2017 0:00  1/1/2017 1:00    ...       392.340  74.897706
1  1/1/2017 1:00  1/1/2017 2:00    ...       393.785  75.173556
2  1/1/2017 2:00  1/1/2017 3:00    ...       388.728  74.208175
3  1/1/2017 3:00  1/1/2017 4:00    ...       386.254  73.735889
4  1/1/2017 4:00  1/1/2017 5:00    ...       393.412  75.102351

[5 rows x 8 columns]

df17_raw.tail()
Out[5]: 
            Date_start          Date_end    ...      Total_Ah   Power_kW
8755  31-12-2017 19:00  31-12-2017 20:00    ...       336.877  64.309819
8756  31-12-2017 20:00  31-12-2017 21:00    ...       327.410  62.502569
8757  31-12-2017 21:00  31-12-2017 22:00    ...       320.638  61.209794
8758  31-12-2017 22:00  31-12-2017 23:00    ...       310.967  59.363600
8759  31-12-2017 23:00     1/1/2018 0:00    ...       306.867  58.580910

[5 rows x 8 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the forward slash (`/`) by a hyphen (`-`), then convert to `datetime` as usual,

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Date_end'].str.replace('/', '-'), errors='coerce')

8755   2017-12-31 20:00:00
8756   2017-12-31 21:00:00
8757   2017-12-31 22:00:00
8758   2017-12-31 23:00:00
8759   2018-01-01 00:00:00
Name: Date_end, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Or vice versa (hyphens to fwd slash).